# Magento Mage::helper('catalog/category')

Tags: php, magento

I've been using this to get the category list:

```
Mage::helper('catalog/category')->getStoreCategories()
```

But i have a problem. It only show the categories that have "YES" on Include in Navigation Menu *.

Here is the whole code.

```
<?php if(Mage::helper('dynamicsitemap')->showCategories()): ?>
<div class="sitempan">
    <h2 class="smh2">Our Categories</h2>
    <?php $_helper = Mage::helper('catalog/category') ?>
    <?php echo $_helper->getStoreCategories() ?>
    <?php 
    $_categories = Mage::helper('catalog/category')->getStoreCategories() ?>
    <?php if (count($_categories) > 0): ?>
        <ul class="sitecatul">
            <?php foreach($_categories as $_category): ?>
            <?php //echo $_category->isEnabled(); ?>
                <li class="cat">
                        <a href="<?php echo $_helper->getCategoryUrl($_category) ?>" title="<?php echo $_category->getName() ?>"><strong class="strongsm"><?php echo $_category->getName() ?></strong></a>
                    <?php $_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_category->getId()) ?>
                    <?php $_subcategories = $_category->getChildrenCategories() ?>
                    <?php if (count($_subcategories) > 0): ?>
                        <ul>
                            <?php foreach($_subcategories as $_subcategory): ?>
                                <?php $_nextcategory = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_subcategory->getId()) ?>
                                <?php $_nextsubcategories = $_nextcategory->getChildrenCategories() ?>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="<?php echo $_helper->getCategoryUrl($_subcategory) ?>" title="<?php echo $_subcategory->getName() ?>">
                                        <?php echo $_subcategory->getName() ?>
                                    </a>
                                    <?php if (count($_nextsubcategories) > 0): ?>
                                    <ul>
                                        <?php foreach($_nextsubcategories as $_nextsubcat): ?>
                                            <li>
                                                <a href="<?php echo $_helper->getCategoryUrl($_nextsubcat) ?>" title="<?php echo $_subcategory->getName() ?> - <?php echo $_nextsubcat->getName() ?>">
                                                    <?php echo $_nextsubcat->getName() ?>
                                                </a>
                                            </li>
                                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                                    </ul>
                                    <?php endif; ?>
                                </li>
                            <?php endforeach; ?>
                        </ul>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </li>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ul>
    <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
```

I want to know what can i do to show all categories, even they are not listed in the menu, to use it as a sitetree.

Answer (score 0):

Try and change line 7 to:

```
$_categories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*');
```

Comment: i need to get them with Mage::helper

Comment: Why?  You can instantiate a model from anywhere. Also, the helper you are loading, guess the first thing it does in `getStoreCategories` - it uses `$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category');`

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
$_categories = Mage::helper('catalog/category')->getStoreCategories();
```

to

```
$_categories = $categories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*')->addIsActiveFilter();
```

Comment: i need to get them with Mage::helper